# Radius of the circumscribed circle

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

We have a triangle with $a=b$. I want to calculate the radius of the circumscribed circle in respect to $a$ and $c$.

We have that the center is the point where the perpendicular bisectors intersect, and the radius is the length to any of the three vertices.

$$$$

From the sinus law we have that $$\frac{a}{\sin\alpha}=\frac{b}{\sin\beta}=\frac{c}{\sin\gamma}=2R$$ where $R$ is the radius of the circumscribed circle.

So, we have that $2r=\frac{a}{\sin\alpha}$. Do we have to write $\sin\alpha$ in respect to $c$ ?

Comment: You can write $\cos \alpha$ in terms of $a$ and $c$. Then you can derive $\sin \alpha$ from there.

Comment: Do you mean by the cosine law? @PaulAljabar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you fear drawing diagrams? They might help. Quite a lot.
[image]

By considering the midpoint of $AB$ and applying the Pythagoran theorem we have
$$ R+\sqrt{R^2-\frac{c^2}{4}} = \sqrt{a^2-\frac{c^2}{4}} $$
That is simple to turn into a quadratic equation, leading to $R=\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{4a^2-c^2}}$.

Comment: I got stuck right now... At which triangle do we apply the pythagorean? Let $O$ be the center and M the midpoint of $AB$. Do we apply the pythagorean theorem at $AOM$ ? But how do we calculate $OM$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar: consider the altitude from $C$. Its length can be computed by applying the Pythagorean theorem to half of $ABC$, leading to the RHS. On the other hand, its length is given by $R+OM$, and $OM$ can be computed by applying the Pythagorean theorem to $OMA$: $$OM=\sqrt{AO^2-AM^2}=\sqrt{R^2-\frac{c^2}{4}}.$$

Comment: I understand!! Thank you so much!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using the symmetry of the isosceles triangle, you have $$\cos\frac{C}{2}=\frac{a}{2R}\implies\cos C=\frac{a^2}{2R^2}-1$$

Also, from the sine rule, you have $\sin C=\frac{c}{2R}$, so combining these gives $$\frac{c^2}{4R^2}+\left(\frac{a^2}{2R^2}-1\right)^2=1$$

This can be rearranged to give $$R^2=\frac{a^4}{4a^2-c^2}$$ and hence $R$ in terms of $a$ and $c$

Comment: How do we get that $\cos\frac{C}{2}=\frac{a}{2R}$ ? By the cosine law?

Comment: @MaryStar by considering the right angled triangle formed by the midpoint of $AC$, the centre of the circle and $C$

Comment: Ah ok!! Thank you very much!! :-)